# Create Layered Window in MFC using OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I need to create a semi-transparent layered window using OpenGL in C++ MFC.
The window will have different alpha values ​​in different places. The transparency of the window will not change when displayed, but the context (e.g. progress bar) will change.

I successfully created a `CDialog`, used `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` on `OnInitDialog` and just drew the window context on the `OnPaint` method using some OpenGL code.
Unfortunately `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` has very limited transparency so I have to use `UpdateLayeredWindow` but I don't know how.

Can someone exmplain to me where and how I should use `UpdateLayeredWindow`? And how I should change context of the window for e.g. progress bar?